# Delete Amazon EC2 terminated instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created an Amazon Free tier Usage Account. I launched two amazon ec2 instances using the online tool. After that one instance was created and running while other was pending which quickly shifted to terminated state.

In description it shows 
State Transition Reason: Server.InternalError: Internal error on launch

Is there any where I could restart the terminated instance or remove it from table. It looks very annoying

Comment: It would be good to see the answer as accepted, which still holds good as of today.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Terminated instances will go away after a few hours. There is nothing you can do to manually remove them.

Not to worry, you won't get billed for it.

Comment: anbhiav you need to mark this as answer. good question good answer.

Comment: @JimThio: Your comment could have gained some attention from OP if it was posted on question. Anyway, I agree that the answer is pretty straight forward and to the point.

Comment: They disappear after 60 minutes.

Comment: ...until they don't. Mine have been around for weeks...

Comment: You can hide terminated instances filtering with this rule:
Instance State : !Terminated

Answer (score 21):

Just want to add a note to the AWS docs on the topic:

> **Terminate Your Instance**
>
> You can delete your instance when you no longer need it. This is
>   referred to as terminating your instance. As soon as the state of an
>   instance changes to shutting-down or terminated, you stop incurring
>   charges for that instance.
>
> You can't connect to or restart an instance after you've terminated
>   it. However, you can launch additional instances using the same AMI.
>
> **Instance Termination**
>
> After you terminate an instance, it remains visible in the console for
>   a short while, and then the entry is automatically deleted. You cannot
>   delete the terminated instance entry yourself.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html

Answer (score 5):

To just hide terminated instances from the table, **click the zoom-out magnifying glass next to *Terminated*** in the *Instance Status* column.

This adds an `Instance State is !terminated` filter.

Comment: Yes, thanks you, this works around this annoying issue